# How to get a file name (from another file) as a parameter for cp linux script

Tags: linux, shell, cp

I have a text file which contains file names that I want to copy to some directory.
Each line represents a file :

filename1

filename2

etc..

I need a shell script that copy all files that are mentioned in the text file (and located in the same directory) to another directory.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not at a computer to test and I'm rusty at bash, or I'd give a full answer. Just Google "bash for each line"and that'll give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
while read -r f; do
    cp "$f" /some-dir
done < file
```